# How to move Contextual Links?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, bootstrap-theme

Added a wrapper inside a `block.tpl.php` called `block-content`:

```
<section id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <div class="block-content">

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php print $content ?>
    </div>

</section>
```

As you can see there is no sign of contextual links in it.

But if you look at the source, contextual links block is put inside the new `block-content`.

[image]

How to move contextual links block outside `block-content` one level up inside `section` so they both become children elements?

Goal is to separate block content wrapped in a separate container without contextual links because it interrupts a lot when it comes to CSS.

I got a solution with jQuery, but it's impractical on every page load for every block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [create multiple tpl.php](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/theming-blocks) files for blocks based on the specific block, the module that created the block.

> Clone block.tpl.php to "block--block--[block-id].tpl.php" file

after try code, I don't' encourage you to do this, but it maybe the solution for you:

```
<section id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <div class="block-content">
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
      <?php endif;?>
      <?php print $content ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

=> Clear cache

Comment: Why can't you apply it to all blocks by default?

Comment: custom template, depending on content or block.